# paypal how to enable a user to purchase with a limited value from my account

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

Is there a method (with an API) that I can enable another user, to purchase a product on the internet, and pay from my account up to a limited amount (i.e $100), without giving him my account's password.
This can be used (for example), to give my child a password to purchase a gift.

Answer (score 0):

No such method to limit the up amount in PayPal except for unverified PayPal account with sending limit in credit card. The best method I think is to contact bank to decrease the sending limit in credit card so that even if your child use this card in any other online platform, he/she can only send a limited amount.